# Assigning an image to inactive slide marker using basic slider jQuery slideshow

Tags: jquery, html, slider

I'm using: http://www.basic-slider.com/ and I figured out that it assigns the 'active' slide a class of 'active-marker' which I figured I could assign a background URL to and worked well. I need to do the same for the inactive, and then get rid of the numbers....looking through the jQuery boggles my mind, was hoping someone could help me apply some cleverness to this problem.

Thanks!

http://www.jamesrobertcook.com/ is the site in question and this is what I'm talking about:

[image: example]

I have the active slider, however the inactive slider doesn't have a class assigned to it and I'm sorta stuck!

Comment: Please see [Why can't I just paste the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: I removed the other link for clarity. Everything is explained in the meta SO answer.

Comment: Sorry, what numbers? You mean on slide numbers? Also, don't understand first question/problem? (this option is for numbers removing: showmarkers : false, // Show individual slide markers So, add this option to slider function call...

Comment: @nevermind I'd like to keep the markers, but replace them with a slightly darker circle.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm...

The marker structure is simply an ol-list, so you can start out by simply and safely formatting *all* markers within the marker-structure using ordinary tag selectors...

... and if you reformat the link in the marker structure to have a zero height font you can get rid of the marker numbers entirely.

Peeking into your code, it would look something like this:

```
ol.bjqs-markers li a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;  /* hide the numbers */

 /* sample default/inactive sample look of 10x10 square of obscure color*/

    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: #abcdef;
}
```

... and for the "inactive" markers

```
ol.bjqs-markers li.active-marker a {
    background-color: #fedcba;  /* change what's needed for the active marker's appearance */
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

> Sorry, what numbers? You mean on slide numbers? Also, don't understand first question/problem? (this option is for numbers removing: showmarkers : false, // Show individual slide markers So, add this option to slider function call... – nevermind

I just used showmarkers: false, it didn't hurt the design any.

Comment: I have just downloaded plugin, and found way to remove numbers completely :  //to get rid of numbers use this instead original:
      var marker = $('<li><a href="#"></a></li>'); ~ 482. line of script... Also, you can add inactive class... Problem is - in one moment - same marker holds both classes... not sure how it will work with css. :)